# Retrieving offline messages not working -XMPP wokkel

Tags: xmpp, chat, twisted, google-talk, wokkel

I have an XMPP chat client using wokkel and twisted and it works fine, but when a user comes online, I send this stanza to get the messages a user received while offline:

```
<iq type='get' id='fetch1'><offline xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/offline'><fetch/></offline></iq>
```

Other messages send and receive just fine but this stanza never returns anything. Any ideas how to debug or what the issue is? (These are google talk users)

Update: Google talk in theory supports XEP-0136 (archiving). When you get a list of support features you get:

```
<feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/archive#otr'/>
<feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/archive#save'/>
```

However, when I then follow this: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html#manage-retrieve
as to how to retrieve archived messages. I send the following stanza:

```
<iq type='get' id='page1'><retrieve xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'/></iq>
```

[Whether or not I include the  tag part of their example, I get a feature not support error back from Google's XMPP server]

```
<iq xmlns='jabber:client' to='x@gmail.com/7EBA7137' type='error' id='page1'>
<retrieve xmlns='urn:xmpp:archive'/><error code='501' type='cancel'>
<feature-not-implemented xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq>
```

Comment: Does the XMPP server support [XEP-13](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html#discover)?